# Git hook to reject commits where filename is longer than specified limit

Tags: git, shell, hook, githooks

I'm looking to create a client-side pre-commit git hook that will prevent a commit if any of the files added to the commit have a file name longer than a specified limit (say 256).

Comment: I have filename limits. Please don't get me wrong, your question is ok, you might have valid reasons to do this, I just wanted to say... I hate filename limits...

Comment: Yes, we have developers who use large super descriptive filenames instead of short and concise ones. This limit is only to enforce a standard.

Comment: Oh, when I said "valid reasons" I was thinking like you have some legacy system that breaks with long filenames. Well be careful with that, you might make some developers unhappy with this. Imho this kind of "standard" should be a guideline, discussed and explained, not a hard enforcing. Anyway, I don't want to presume what is happening in your company.

Comment: Haha yes. I meant to say as a guideline. And yes, it does break deployments due to the filenames being too long.

Comment: Are you looking for total name length, or component name length? That is, consider `thisisoneverylongpathnamethatgoesonandonandonasyoucansee` vs `this/is/one/very/long/path/name/that/goes/on/and/on/as/you/can/see`. Both are long, but one has only one *component* that is very long; the second has many components, each of which is short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# .git/hooks/pre-commit
# Checks that the file about to be committed
# doesn't have a name longer than 256 characters

if test $(git diff --cached --diff-filter=A --name-only | xargs -0 basename | tr -d '\n' | wc -c) -gt 256
then
  echo "The staged file name is longer than 256 characters"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Here's a breakdown of the command:

- `git diff --cached --diff-filter=A --name-only` Gets the paths of the staged files
- `xargs -0 basename` For each of those paths, extract the file name
- `tr -d '\n'` Removes the newline characters
- `wc -c` Returns the number of characters in the file name

This example works if you have only one staged file. You'll have to develop it further by running the same check in a loop for all staged paths.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works as expected. But there is one tiny issue. The character count is way off and it seems to increase with each pipe symbol (|). So, if my filename+extension was 13 characters, the output would say it's 15 characters. How can I workaround this?

Comment: It was counting the newline `\n` characters. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're summing up all added files, so if the commit adds 1000 files, each of which has a three-character name, your `wc -c` will say that there are 3000 characters in the (assumed-to-be-single) added file. That ... seems wrong. :-) Also, you probably want to disable rename detection so that renames count as new files, and avoid user settings, so best to use `git diff-index` directly here. Remember that we want to compare `HEAD` vs the index.

Comment: My example works for just one staged file, as stated in the comment. That's why I led by saying that it was a "starting point". Maybe it wasn't obvious, so I clarified that. OP would have to develop it further by running the same check for all staged paths.